# An internal error occurred during: "Start Ruble bundle manager"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana3

I've install the Aptana3 Eclipse plugin, I am using eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855.

Each time I launch eclipse I see an error dialog that says:

An internal error occurred during: "Start Ruble bundle manager".
java.lang.NullPointerException

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you look at the .log file in the .metadata folder to see what is causing the exception?

Answer (score 30):

I was having the same problem after a fresh install of Eclipse and Aptana.

What fixed it for me was very close to what Jason mentioned in his Answer. I checked the available software sites in Eclipse --> Preferences --> Install/Update --> Available Software Sites.

In this window there was an option for Aptana that was checked. I had given it a name of "Aptana" previously and the location was "http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install".

There was a second location listed for Aptana at "http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/" but this option was not checked nor did it have a name. I gave it the name "Aptana Update" and I put a check in the box. I then restarted Eclipse and the error went away.

Let me note that I am using: 

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Build id: 20130919-0819

AND

Aptana Studio 3

Version: 3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq

Answer (score 5):

Try checking the available software sites in Eclipse --> preferences. Use the search field in preferences to get there quickly. I noticed there was an entry for:

www.apanta.com

The above address isn't the location of the package. Once I unchecked that box and selected the one for:

Apanta http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

it started without the error. Not sure if this is the full solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: For me, the solution was to give the Aptana bundle a correct name after it had crashed during install. I has been working without any issues but the initial error message.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your .log to find which bundle has an issue.

Then uncheck, remove or change wrong url in the install/update available software sites : Eclipse -> Preferences -> Install/update -> Available Sofware Sites
(to check this url, just copy/paste and look in browser..)

Aptana update site (at current time...) : http://update.aptana.com/update/studio/3.2

Answer (score 1):

Install the support file for Windows 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/zlib.php

this solved my problem in Windows. As by Linux it comes as default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using rvm to install zlib.  I looked through my log file (Eclipse: Help > Aptana > View Log File) and saw a zlib error message right before the NullPointerException. If zlib isn't in your log, this probably won't fix your problem ;-)

My system (Ubuntu) already had zlib1g and zlib1g-dev installed.

```
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the Folder *bundles* in your installation.

```
<apptanaFolder>/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles
```

do a chmod to allow the user read and write to this folder:

```
chmod 775 <apptanaFolder>/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles -R
```

Be Happy, cause you solve your problem!

Here in German Language:
http://wiki.xstable.de/doku.php/entwicklungsumgebung:eclipse:troubleshooting#ruble_manager

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122#c51
I confirm it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of Jonathan to no avail, although one of the adresses for Aptana was indeed unchecked and unmarked.

What worked for me was simply updating the plugins though Help --> Check for Updates.