# Aptana Studio 3.4.2 Eclipse Plugin Fails with Internal Errors After Installing on Win 7 Pro 64-bit PC running Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse-plugin, windows-7-x64, aptana3, eclipse-kepler

After spending time trying to find/download Aptana Studio version 3.5.0 and learning on Stackoverflow that the developers of Aptana Studio pulled this version (with no message or news from Aptana) I have repeatedly tried to install the currently available version of Aptana Studio 3 Eclipse Plugin (3.4.2 according to Aptana download site) on Eclipse Kepler IDE for Java Developers (eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip) on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit machine by following the Aptana Studio install instructions from their web site exactly (http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start):

*Installing via Eclipse
Please copy the following Update Site URL to your clipboard and then follow the steps listed below to add this URL to your Available Software Sites list. Attempting to access this URL using your web browser will return an Access Denied error.
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

From the Help menu, select Install New Software... to open the Install New Software dialog.
Paste the URL for the update site into the Work With text box, and hit the Enter (or Return) key.
In the populated table below, check the box next to the name of the plug-in, and then click the Next button.
Click the Next button to go to the license page.
Choose the option to accept the terms of the license agreement, and click the Finish button.
You may need to restart Eclipse to continue.*

The install completes but when I try and launch Aptana Studio I continually get the following errors and thus can't launch the app:

"Problem Occurred - Launching the studio portal has encountered a problem. An Internal Error has occurred"

"An internal error occurred during: "Start Ruble bundle manager".
java.lang.NullPointerException"

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app several times and have the same problem. I have scoured the web, Stackoverflow, Aptana's support sites including bugs/issues, etc. but have not found any solution.

It is very frustrating that the most basic function of trying to use a new app/tool ***i.e. installing it***, doesn't work and I have already wasted several days on this and am ready to ditch Aptana Studio for another web IDE. I hope the Aptana devs can fix whatever is causing this problem ASAP but in the meantime I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with any solutions to this problem so I could at least get it to successfully install so I can launch the app and try it out.

EDIT: .log file contents (from .metadata directory) after installing Aptana   Studio Eclipse Plugin:

```
    !SESSION 2014-05-08 01:59:13.298 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-05-08 01:59:37.932
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-05-08 01:59:37.932
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+D:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+D,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.commands.Display,Display,
        Display result of evaluating selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@90afea4,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+D,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.commands.download,Download...,
        ,
        Category(com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.commands.category,File Transfer,File Transfer Commands,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@30d3c59f,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+D,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.radrails.rails.ui.command.debug.server,Debug Server,
        ,
        Category(org.radrails.rails.ui.category,Rails,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1f5362c4,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-05-08 01:59:37.932
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+U:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+U,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.search.occurrences.in.file.quickMenu,Show Occurrences in File Quick Menu,
        Shows the Occurrences in File quick menu,
        Category(org.eclipse.search.ui.category.search,Search,Search command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1b7941ed,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+U,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.commands.upload,Upload...,
        ,
        Category(com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.commands.category,File Transfer,File Transfer Commands,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@35d73cb2,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-08 01:59:40.512
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElementsRecursive(ModelServiceImpl.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.Portal$1.runInUIThread(Portal.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-08 02:00:13.427
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElementsRecursive(ModelServiceImpl.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.Portal$1.runInUIThread(Portal.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-08 02:00:24.084
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElementsRecursive(ModelServiceImpl.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.addPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
    at com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.Portal$1.runInUIThread(Portal.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/633591/everytime-eclipse-starts-i-get-this-error-message-aptana-plugin or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133269/an-internal-error-occurred-during-start-ruble-bundle-manager?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your mentioning these threads. I had already seen these and tried the recommended solutions none of which worked. These threads also only talk about the "start Ruble bundle manager" error but not the other "Launching the studio portal has encountered a problem. An Internal Error has occurred". Still hoping for additional ideas or solutions.

Comment: The entry in the log related to it not starting would be needed, then, as it hopefully has a clue as to why.

Comment: Thanks very much nitind. I am assuming you are asking to see a diagnostic log (please let me know if you need something else) so I ran a diagnostic test after installing the Aptana Eclipse plug-in again (Help-Aptana-Run diagnostic test) which produced the following diagnostic log:

Comment: @nitind - please see my log above added to original post.

Comment: I meant the actual .log file if one was generated, in the workspace's .metadata directory.

Comment: @nitind - I replaced the diagnostic test log with the contents of the .log file under the .metadata directory. I uninstalled and reinstalled both Eclipse and Aptana Studio again to see if it would work and now I only get the first error ("Problem Occurred - Launching the studio portal has encountered a problem. An Internal Error has occurred") when I try and launch Aptana Studio, the second error is not occurring any more.